# Flutter Firebase Firestore Queries with Document Fieldpaths with maps

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to sort a list of documents based on whether another user has seen it or not.
My database structure is the following:

```
following (Document Field){
Dy2k9f2m7uXnnBBPHssPxJucCrK2 : true (Map)
HOIXdQkoerRBgYCGHFRylQD2VKi1 : true (Map)
}
```

I tried running this command

```
print(
user.data()['following'].toString(),
);
```

and recieved the output

> {HOIXdQkoerRBgYCGHFRylQD2VKi1: true, Dy2k9f2m7uXnnBBPHssPxJucCrK2:
> true}

But I want to know whether a specified user id say HOIXdQkoerRBgYCGHFRylQD2VKi1 has the value true or false.

How do I go about it? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore map type fields accessed with `user.data()['following']` return a `Map<String, dynamic>`, so you can treat it like any other Map in dart.  If you want to assume it contains `bool` values:

```
Map<String, bool> following = user.data()['following'];
bool seen = following['the-user-id-to-check'];
```

Comment: The output shows

type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, bool>'

Comment: So, capitalize the S in string.

Comment: I guess the problem again is because the datatype is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

As Doug suggested, The issue here is that the value is probably dynamic.
You can cast it to a bool variable :

```
bool see = false;
String userKey = "Dy2k9f2m7uXnnBBPHssPxJucCrK2"; // <-- User Key

print(
  see = user.data()['following'][userKey] as bool, // <-- cast as bool
);
```